# реализация абстрактного метода, как приватного метода

Tags: java

У меня был некий класс, который помимо всего прочего осуществлял фильтрацию некого внутреннего списка. мне понадобился другой класс, который абсолютно такой же как и первый, но отличается алгоритмом фильтрации.

Я решил сделать абстрактный класс с абстрактной процедурой фильтрации, которую каждый класс будет реализовывать по своему.

Однако процедура фильтрации у меня была private, а абстрактный метод private быть не может. Т.е. получается я могу создать только класс-наследник, где эта процедура будет public(ну ли protected, что тоже не желательно).

С одной стороны оно и как public работать будет, но метод вызывать извне не планируется, он чисто служебный, а поэтому  public (или protected) по сути будет ошибкой. С другой стороны можно реализовать не абстрактный класс-родитель с пустым телом метода-фильтра и переопределить этот метод у наследников, но это выглядит как "костыль" т.к. не абстрактный метод-родитель в этом случае окажется полноценным классом, который тем не менее "не работает".

Какой подход в данной ситуации будет правильным?

Comment: "метод вызывать извне не планируется, он чисто служебный" - делайте его protected. То есть его видит только наследник

Comment: "С другой стороны можно реализовать не абстрактный класс-родитель с пустым телом метода-фильтра и переопределить этот метод у наследников" - так тогда этот метод должен быть либо public, либо protected, либо видимости по дефолту. В чем разница то с абстрактным методом?

Comment: тут есть несколько вариантов. 1) 1 абстрактный класс родитель и два наследника. 2) два класса, один из которых переопределяет нужный метод. 3)реализовать паттерн шаблонный метод. 4)воспользоваться лямбдой для передачи поведения в метод с целью определения способа фильтрации. покажите классы с фильтрами, тогда можно ответить конкретнее

Comment: Если переопределять по второму варианту, то там будет public.А разница в том, что не абстрактный класс без  реализации метода будет выглядеть как рабочий/самостоятельный класс, но таковым не будет.

Comment: Нет, [это будет абстрактный класс](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Comment: лямбда в метод интересное решение

Comment: шаблонный метод - не менее интересное. вы явно недооцениваете ооп

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image: Рисунок]

Так пойдёт? Если не то, то уточни задачу)
iNplement))) sorry)
implement

Comment: Ну... по сути да...

Comment: @Dmitrii Подождите, но метод то `public`.

Comment: его можно как private обозначить. Хотя в ответе  не обозначено.

Comment: верно Дмитрий, можно и private (моя невнимательность))

Comment: @openman2077error Подумал, почему-то, что это интерфейс. А с каких пор можно понижать область видимости метода родителя? Мне, вот, `eclipse` дает ошибку. Что логично - если ты используешь наследника в шкуре родителя, то у тебя должна быть возможность вызвать метод.